# Which method of performing statistical analysis is more efficient?

Tags: php, parsing, file-upload

I have a script which parses log files and ends up with a particular set of data.

Lets pretend that $data contains all of the data gained from the log file.

Is it better to:

1. Hang on to $data, open a connection to the database, add $data to the current database values, write(update) the new values to the database, and then close the connection, 
   or
2. Write each new set of $data to the database as a new "transaction" - meaning each time we get a new set of $data, we'll have a corresponding record(row) in the database for it, and perform analysis AS-NEEDED at the time of request?

tl;dr: Immediately update database with new values, post-analysis, and discard the temporary $data or keep all $data in database and perform analysis on the fly as needed?

My thoughts: Option 1 seems more efficient, but what if 2 people are uploading files at the same time? Will there ever be a case where two people are working with and updating to the database 2 different sets of data without locking it to one transaction at a time? If this is the case, I'd love to setup some kind of parsing queue, but not sure how to do that :]

Comment: We're going to need more information.  How expensive (time wise) is the data processing?  How often will it be processed?  Will processing it ahead of time be worth while?  Or will the processed data only be viewed once or twice?  Is table locking something you need to avoid?  Will you ever need the original data again (could always store it and the processed data)?  So on.

Comment: Oh man..I wish I could answer this accurately. Lots of things will be recorded, so I would say it may eventually evolve into an expensive process. From what we plan to have read in from the parser, I think processing ahead of time will not only be worth it, but necessary. That being said, I think we would benefit from having individual records saved, in case we want to calculate something we didn't in the past, so I can't decide on how I should go about this.  Now that I'm thinking about it, I think we should save all records, and also calculate on the fly. We can try to optimize in the future

Comment: Since we are still testing with an individual log file offline on a WAMP server, I don't see why we can't try both methods - run the same parser X amount of times and calculate progressively, and also upload the same data to the database X amount of times and calculate stats on the fly per request, and see which is faster! Easiest way..